# Is it possible to pass data into a component that is being iterated?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, mobx, firestorter

Im trying to pass down data from state into a component that is being iterated.
I am using React Native and Firestorter (which uses mobx as well) to get data from firebase. Im specifically looking for a way to pass down state, while .map is running.

```
const latestEP = new Collection("episodes");

const Dashboard = observer(
  class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isPlaying: false,
        isBuffering: true
      };
    }

    render() {
      latestEP.query = ref => ref.orderBy("id", "desc").limit(1);
      return (
        <View style={styles.cont}>
          <View style={styles.logoBTN}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Logo />
            </View>

            {/* Buttons//////////////////////////////////////// */}
            <View style={styles.buttonGroup}>
              <Button
                color="#427389"
                title="Episode Archive"
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Previous")}
              />
              <Button
                color="#427389"
                title="Logout"
                onPress={() => logoutUser()}
              />
            </View>
          </View>

          {/*Content/////////////////////////////////////////// */}
          <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
            {latestEP.docs.map(doc => (
              <DashboardItem key={doc.id} doc={doc} />
            ))}
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
);

const DashboardItem = observer(({ doc }) => {
  const { name, id, date, url, description } = doc.data;
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the state variables to the props:

```
{latestEP.docs.map(doc => (
  <DashboardItem key={doc.id} doc={doc} isPlaying={this.state.isPlaying} isBuffering={this.state.isBuffering}/>
))}
```